# FormData can be seen when called on the onSubmit. However, passing this on the server action results to null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase

I am using NextJS 14 and Supabase.

I have a reusable component that I use

```
import { useState } from 'react';

interface MyInputProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  value: string | number;
  onChange: (name: string, value: string | number) => void;
  placeholder?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  type?: 'text' | 'number';
}

const MyInput = ({
  label,
  name,
  value,
  onChange,
  placeholder,
  required = false,
  type = 'text',
}: MyInputProps) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>('');

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const inputValue = type === 'number' ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : e.target.value;
    onChange(name, inputValue);
    setError('');
  };

  const validateInput = () => {
    if (required && (!value || (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim() === ''))) {
      setError('This field is required');
    } else {
      setError('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="mb-4">
      <label className="block text-lg font-semibold text-blue-700 mb-2">{label}</label>
      <input
        type={type}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onBlur={validateInput}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      {error && <p className="text-red-500 text-lg italic mt-2">{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyInput;
```

And I have these code on the submit form: Now, if I `console.log(formData)` on this part, I can view all of the data in the console:
[image]

```
'use client'
...imports

interface FormData {
  name: string;
  landmark: string;
  ..other inputs
}

export default function WaterStationProfileForm() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>({
    name: "",
    landmark: "",
    ..other inputs
  });

  async function onSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior

    console.log(formData,"formData under waterStation file form")
   
    const res = await addWaterStation(new FormData(event.currentTarget))
    setMessage(res.message);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <MyInput
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        value={formData.name}
        onChange={(name, value) => setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value })}
        required={true}
        type="text"
      />   
      <MyInput
        label="Landmark"
        name="landmark"
        value={formData.landmark}
        onChange={(name, value) => setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value })}
        required={true}
        type="text"
      />
      ...other input fields
    </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the codes for the server actions. If I `console.log(formData)`, it results to `FormData { [Symbol(state)]: [] }`

codes:

```
    'use server'

import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { cookies } from "next/headers"


export default async function addWaterStation(formData: FormData): Promise<{ message: string }> {
    console.log(formData, "form data under water station.ts")
    const supabase =createServerComponentClient({cookies})
    const {data: {user}} = await supabase.auth.getUser();
    const formDataAddress = `${formData.get('buildingNumber')}, ${formData.get('street')}, ${formData.get('zone')}`

    try{
        const station_name = formData.get('name')
        ...other data here
        
        const {data, error} = await supabase.from('water_refilling_station')
            .insert({
                station_name,
                ..other data here
            }).select()
        
        if(error){
            return {message: `${error.message}  - unable to save`}
        } 

        revalidatePath('/n')
        return{message: 'Succesfully Added the Water Station Information'}
    }catch(e){
        return {message: "Failed to submit the form."}
    }

}
```

Comment: Confirm that `event.currentTarget` is the same as what you are logging here `console.log(formData,"formData under waterStation file form")`

Comment: I can’t test but looking at the API specification, the `FormDataEvent` object fired has a [`formData` instance property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormDataEvent/formData) which you should use to get the `formData` you need to send over the wire. [See react forms also.](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/form)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```js
const res = await addWaterStation(new FormData(event.currentTarget))
```

To this instead

```js
const res = await addWaterStation(event.formData);
```

[FormDataEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormDataEvent)

Comment: It still did not work. However, I chose another route for this and refractored the codes